# While statement that does something as long as there's an object in the array that has certain property values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, while-loop

I have a simple array of objects.

How do I make a while statement that does something as long as there's an object in the array that has certain property values?

```
let shirts = new Array();

let item1 = {
  "color": "blue",
  "size": "small"
}
shirts.push(item1);

while (shirts.some(e => e.color === "blue")) {
  // do something
}
```

So, while `shirts` has an item with the color blue and size small, do something.

I found some solutions but they only check for one value, and I need to make it two:

```
while (shirts.some(e => e.color === "blue")) {
      // do something
    }
```

It's a while loop so I can keep modifying the values programmatically, until it finally doesn't match.

Comment: please remember to accept an answer if it helped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be better to define the item your'e referencing, this will help debug and future you when going through the code

```js
let this_is_true = shirts.some(e => e.color === 'blue' && e.size === 'small');

while (this_is_true){
  // ..

  //re-check for every iteration
  this_is_true = shirts.some(e => e.color === 'blue' && e.size === 'small')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (shirts.some(e => e.color === 'blue' && e.size === 'small')) {
  // do something
}
```

or

```
while (shirts.filter(e => e.color === 'blue' && e.size === 'small').length > 0) {
  // do something
}
```